# AJAX call in Java Controller without jquery

Tags: java, ajax

I'm using following code to make a AJAX call using jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:8080/v1/student?studentId=a3a802fcc7604a46a49d5c57150d8d99",
    type : "GET",
    crossDomain : true,
    timeout : 50000,
    success : function(response) {
        console.log("SUCCESS: ", response);
        loadSidebar(response);              
    },
    error : function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("ERROR: ", error);
    }
});
```

I would like to make this call using Java in my Controller instead of using jquery and get the JSON response in my response variable.

Can anyone help me out to convert the above code to JAVA code?

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it in my Java Controller as follows:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/v1/student?studentId=a3a802fcc7604a46a49d5c57150d8d99");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    con.setConnectTimeout(50000);

    if (con.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + con.getResponseCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((con.getInputStream())));
    String output = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(output);

    con.disconnect();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```